# How to use LOAD DATA INFILE mysql syntax in magento?

Tags: magento2, database

```
$write = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$write->beginTransaction();
 $query = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $partCsvPath . "' "
          . "INTO TABLE " . $resource->getTableName('csv')
          . " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','"
          . " LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'"
          . " (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)";
$write->exec($query);
$write->commit();
```

This gives me the following error:

`SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1148 The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version`

I can execute this query in MySQL just fine but not through Magento.

Is there any solution to this? without `local` this gives me permission denied error.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not about Magento