# How to enable LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, database, zend-framework, php-pdo

So far I found [this closed question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105639/how-to-use-load-data-infile-mysql-syntax-in-magento) and solutions for Magento 2, but I'm hoping there's a solution for Magento 1 as well. This question should not be closed like the other one because it IS specific to Magento 1.

In mysql, I checked what my `local_infile` variable looks like:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'local_infile';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| local_infile  | ON    |
+---------------+-------+
```

And yet, when I run my query, I still get the warning:

```
ERR (3): Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE forbidden  in /var/www/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

Now, in Magento 2, the solution is to add a line in `app/etc/env.php` to say

```
'driver_options' => array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE => true)
```

However, in Magento 1, my file structure under `app/etc/` has only a `modules` directory and the following files:

```
config.xml
local.xml
local.xml.additional
local.xml.template
```

As you can see, there is no `env.php` or any `.php` files at all, so I have no idea where that line would go, or if there's a completely different way to solve this.

Comment: What is the content of your /Statement/Pdo.php?  LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE is likely looking for a pattern that looks like data such as CSV or other type of data.  Try bing.com search for "Magento load forbidden" for other clues.  And here is another link.  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73134/403-forbidden-on-magento-admin-category-url

Comment: That file is totally irrelevant. It's just the `_execute` function. Line 228 is just the return statement from it: `return $this->_stmt->execute($params);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this options to solve your problem.

Open the DB connection settings in the local.xml file and add this:

```
<driver_options>
         <MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE>true</MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE>
</driver_options>
```

If it doesn't work you can download the script [here](https://github.com/kschroeder/Magento_Mysql_SSL), copy it to your project in the appropriate directories and then in the connection setting of the local.xml file use this:

```
<secure_driver_options>
    <MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE>true</MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE>
</secure_driver_options>
```

You will receive something like this:

```
<config>
    <global>
        ...
        <resources>
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    ...
                    <secure_driver_options>
                        <MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE>true</MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE>
                    </secure_driver_options>
                    ...
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
        </resources>
        ...
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Adding driver options to the config file did not work for me unfortunately. But I haven't tried the script yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to query `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` in Magento 1. First, `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE` is an integer, and we cannot add an int node name in the config XML. After digging through how `$this->_getWriteAdapter()` is created in the resource model and especially `Mage_Core_Model_Resource::_newConnection()`, I came up with the following way:

```php
// In your custom resource model

class Vendor_Module_Model_Resource_Custom extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract
{
    //...
    /**
     * Get the DB connection with option PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE
     *
     * @return Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql|Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface|false
     */
    protected function _getLocalInfileConnection()
    {
        return $this->_connections['local_infile']
            ?? $this->_connections['local_infile'] = $this->_newLocalInfileConnection();
    }

    /**
     * Create a new DB connection with option PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE
     * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42065100/488609
     *
     * @return Magento_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql|Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface|false
     */
    protected function _newLocalInfileConnection()
    {
        $write = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
        $config = $write->getConfig();
        $config['driver_options'][PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_LOCAL_INFILE] = true;

        $className = get_class($write);
        $connection = new $className($config);
        if ($connection instanceof Varien_Db_Adapter_Interface) {
            // run after initialization statements
            if (!empty($config['initStatements'])) {
                $connection->query($config['initStatements']);
            }
        } else {
            $connection = false;
        }

        return $connection;
    }

    /**
     * Load temp table with CSV file.
     *
     * @param string $file Path and file name to load data from.
     * @return int Number of rows loaded.
     */
    public function loadTempTable($file)
    {
        $adapter = $this->_getLocalInfileConnection(); 
        $sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file'"
          ' INTO TABLE ' . $this->_getTempTableName()
        //. ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY \'\t\'  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY \'"\''; // Default delimited is tab
        . ' CHARACTER SET utf8mb4'
        . ' (' . implode(',', $this->getTempTableCols()) . ')';

        return $adapter->query($sql)->rowCount();
    }
}
```